# How can I write tests for methods using the instagram api/gem mocking the actual service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, instagram

In a project I am accessing instagram using the gem provided. How do you guys write tests that don’t require calls to the service / mock it and stay meaningful? (I am using rspec, but this should not be the issue)

Scenario: I am subscribed to some tags, upon receiving the post from instagram about new entities, I query the tags, get the provided media ids, query the ids and import the result. (A bit complicated, but this seems to be how it is done)

I’d be grateful for some actual code examples, too…

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I stubbed out some similar calls to Etsy in a project I worked on recently.

```
module EtsyStubs

    def stub_etsy_find_listing(options = {})
        if options[:fail]
          Etsy::Listing.stub(:find).and_return(nil)
          return
        end

        etsy_item = OpenStruct.new(
          state: options[:state],
          price: options[:price],
          result: {
            "currency_code" => "USD",
            "Variations" => []
          }
        )

        Etsy::Listing.stub(:find).and_return(etsy_item)
      end

end
```

This lives in a file in the spec/support directory and needs to be included from the spec_helper.rb like `config.include(EtsyStubs)`.

You can include it for all specs from the spec_hlper.rb with:

```
config.before(:each) do
    stub_etsy_find_listing
end
```

or can include it before individual tests.

The key is choosing an object to return that responds to the appropriate calls.  In my case, a simple OpenStruct that will respond to things like etsy_item.price, etsy_item.state worked well.